# How or When is the Lozenge symbol used?

Tags: typography

I could find articles in Wikipedia that explain what each typographical symbol means and how it is used in print (e.g. pilcrow, section, dagger) but I couldn't find any information about the Lozenge mark/sign/symbol/character (◊ or [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lozenge#Encodings) U+25CA).

I know it's being used in [modal logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lozenge#Modal_logic) and math, but is it (or has it ever been) used in **English** text?

Comment: Are you interested in white or black lozange?

Comment: @Carlo_R No preference really. I am just curious as to why I couldn't find any reference to its typographical use other than logic or math. Does this mean that, unlike ¶ or § or †, it hasn't really been used in textbooks other than the math ones?

Comment: I reckon it could be used as a [bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_%28typography%29).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every entry of *lozenge* in the [OED](http://www.oed.com) lists a heraldic, artistic, or mathematical usage.

From this we can assert that any usage in English text has, so far, been ornamental (e.g. as a list marker), or descriptive of things that incorporate the shape itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's not used in text (although it could be used decoratively, in a border or as a rule or bullet). It's a mathematical symbol.